# Losing contents of char**array when passed to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, char

I have the following structs in my on-going struggle to eventually create some kind of shell (based eventually around  `execvp()`.

```
struct commands {
    char cmdname[30]; // The name of the command
    enum ActionType action; /* char action[30];  what action to take */
};

struct userinput {
    struct commands theaction; //The chosen action
    char cmdentered[100]; // The cmd entered
    char **anyargs; //The tokenised command
    int argcount; //Argument count
};
```

And I initialise  `anyargs`  using malloc and create an array of strings with one string per argument to be passed on to the execvp.

I then get user input, convert the input into tokens stored in anyargs and examine the strings to find out what sort of action needs to be taken and store that in an enum.

All these methods are done by passing the pointer to the struct  `userinput`  as method parameters - which works fine. HOWEVER when I pass the pointer to the struct to a nested function, the `char** anyargs` becomes empty.

I hope the code I've added provides a solution to the answer! On another observation - when passed to a function inside a function, the actual value of the pointer doesn't change - only the dereferenced contents of the pointer.

Any help would be most gratefully received! I've tried to strip the code down to the areas I think are causing the issue! 
Thank you!

```
int main() {

    struct commands cmdlist[4]; //Array of structures with all commands in them
    memset(cmdlist, 0, sizeof(cmdlist));

    struct userinput userentry = { { { 0 } } }; //Structure containing input
    userentry.theaction = cmdlist[0]; //Initialize empty command
    userentry.anyargs = calloc(100, sizeof(char));

    runEntry(&userentry, cmdlist); //Pass struct to function 

    free(userentry.anyargs);

    return 0;
}

int runEntry(struct userinput *userentry, struct commands thecmds[]) {
    int retval = 0;
    int childpid = 0;
    int processStatus;
    printf("\n    ... running cmd: \n\n");

    printUserEntry(userentry); //in printUserEntry, 
                               //userentry->anyargs[0] = NULL - why?
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the *real* `runEntry` look like, because this one has two parameters on the call from `main`, but three in the actual implementation provided. This isn't tagged C++, and last I checked (been awhile, admittedly) C doesn't support optional args (not to be confused with variadic args). Is `runEntry` prototyped before its use in `main()`, or are you just using the compiler assumed `int fn()` default.

Comment: @WhozCraig The real runEntry is around 100 lines and contains a bool *quit - I omitted everything after printUserEntry(userentry); where the debugger told me that userentry->anyargs[0] was becoming empty.

Comment: And the parameter mismatch from the *call* to the *implementation*?

Comment: Is not a parameter mismatch in my actual code where i haven't made an attempt to omit data for clarity - I didnt want to do a code dump - likewise I haven't prototyped <code>runEntry</code>, included headers or other such in this question.

Comment: I understand, so long as you understand that such a mismatch is *easily* contributory to the problem, and thus an utter red-herring only you're aware of. Posting summary is fine (and *highly* encouraged) so long as it demonstrates the problem and doesn't introduce tangent problems due to the strip-down. I hope that is clear. It looks like Paul is on to something in your problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate that - thanks. Unfortunately changing the malloc to calloc hasn't helped. When the struct is passed to the nested function, the contents of anyargs is still lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've allocated 100 bytes worth of `char *` elements in `anyargs`. You haven't initialized those pointers, though. The fact that `anyargs[0]` happens to contain `NULL` is nice, but not guaranteed. `malloc()` doesn't initialize the allocated space.

In other words, when you say:

```
userentry.anyargs = malloc(100);
```

you've created:

```
userentry.anyargs = {
  ???, // uninitialized char * 
  ???, // and another
  ???, // and another
  ...
  ???  // (100 / sizeof(char *)) entries later
};
```

You can explicitly initialize those to NULL in a loop:

```
for ( i = 0; i < (100 / sizeof(char *)); ++i )
  userentry.anyargs[i] = NULL;
```

(or use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` to ensure everything is zeroed out).

or you can allocate some space to them:

```
for ( i = 0; i < (100 / sizeof(char *)); ++i )
  userentry.anyargs[i] = malloc(50);  // or some other length
```

or just set them directly in `runEntry()`:

```
userentry.anyargs[0] = "foo";
userentry.anyargs[1] = strdup(something);
```

Comment: Or perhaps realize that `100/sizeof(char*)` is not actually wanted.

Comment: Almost certainly that, too, but that's far from the issue at hand.